# Fail to retrieve correct input value from dynamic textbox

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have input value which is rendered for `each` data. For fully understanding the problem, see this gif:

[image]

It seems, I could't get correct input value

**client/js**

```
var itemEvents = {
  "click #submitReply" : function(e,t) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var el = t.find("#textReply");
    Repliess.insert({
      commentId: commentId,
      text: el.value
    });
    el.value = "";
  }
};
Template.commentList.events(itemEvents);
```

**input value**

```
<div class="ui input">
    <input id="textReply" type="text" placeholder="Add Comment...">
    <button id="submitReply" type="submit" class="ui button">Submit</button>
  </div>
```

Anyone know how to get it work properly? thank Youu..

Comment: Could you show your `each` loop

Comment: also it's better to replace all ids with class names, since it's not good when you have same ids on your page

Comment: hello @ZuzEL I have posted additional information. changing id with class don't work. maybe because it render the same class..thank Youu,,

Comment: @Karina where is your events you need to use the events on the `reply` template.

Comment: Hi @MarkUretsky no events. They are all data context from mongodb

Comment: @KarinaL Hi, I mean the events for button submit (click event) if they are on the parent template you always catch the first input, You need to get the current template input with this: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_$ If you can share more of your code for the template events, I can easily show you how to fix this.

Comment: hello @MarkUretsky. I had provided at the question. var itemEvents = {
  "click #submitReply" : function(e,t) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var el = t.find("#textReply");
    Repliess.insert({
      commentId: commentId,
      text: el.value
    });
    el.value = "";
  }
};
Template.commentList.events(itemEvents);. Which submit button do you mean? thank Youu..

Comment: I updated my answer. Put events on `commentForm` template

Comment: @ZuzEL Why i can't think of that... it's work!! thank You Sir,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it takes first textarea which is empty. Try this:

```
Template.commentForm.events({
"click #submitReply" : function(e,t) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var el = $(e.currentTarget).closest(".ui.input").find("#textReply");
    Repliess.insert({
      commentId: commentId,
      text: el.val()
    });
    el.val("");
  }
})
```

Comment: hello @ZuzEl... thank You for your answer. unfortunately your code don't work even at the first element. see my edited answer,,,